# Recovery tha value of CommandArgument set on GridView1 RowEditing in c#

Tags: c#, gridview, row, edit

I need recovery the value of **CommandArgument** set on :

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server"
      CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Rec").ToString().Contains("100") ? 1 : 0 %>'
      ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Rec").ToString().Contains("100") ? "~/icon1.gif" : "~/icon0.gif"%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

In the `GridView1_RowEditing` :

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    int SelectRec = int.Parse((sender as ImageButton).CommandArgument);
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData(); 
}
```

I have tried with adding on `GridView1_RowEditing`, without success :

```
int SelectRec = int.Parse((sender as ImageButton).CommandArgument);
```

How to do resolve this?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

Comment: you get any error?

Comment: @Badiparmagi **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** on **SelectRec**

Comment: maybe your Eval object is null. can you try to get id like this: `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Rec")%>'`

Comment: so you will find out if it is null by debugging.

Comment: @Badiparmagi The value of **Eval("Rec").ToString()** is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get **value** of `CommandArgument` from `GridView1.DataKeys`:

```
int SelectRec = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].Value);
```